# Alias in QGIS disappearing

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes, alias

Does anyone know why the 'alias'  not saved when I export a layer to a shp file? So, I made alias in the file when I exported. After I opened exported shp file and properties->attribute form/fields are empty.

[image]

Since the names of columns are long, having the alias is critical.

Comment: Shapefile format does not support alias names. QGIS saves the alias names into the project file. Not even ESRI can store alias names into shapefiles https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/field-alias-and-shapefiles/td-p/310977.

Comment: try using a modern standard format like geopackage.

Answer (score 2):

Shapefile can't store alias so you can define them in your project but when exporting they get lost.

One way to keep alias is to save a .qml ([QGIS layer style file](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_file_formats.html#qml-the-qgis-style-file-format)) along the shp. if the .qml and the other shp files are in the same folder and share the same name, the .qml will be automatically loaded and you will get the alias name set. (Of course as .qml is a QGIS specific format this only work with QGIS, if you share the shapefile with people using some other software the .qml won't work)